# raspberry piにunionfs-fuseを導入するとSDカードの内容が消える

Tags: raspberry-pi

Raspberry pi3で電源断を簡単に行いたいと考え、
unionfs-fuseを導入しました。
いくつかのサイト様を参考にインストール、設定は完了したのですが
一度シャットダウンさせると起動しなくなり
SDカードの内容を確認するとファイルがすべて空になっていました。

下記の手順で導入を行いました。

事前にswapファイル、logファイルなどをRAMディスクに移すなどの設定は済ませています。

1. パッケージ導入

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install unionfs-fuse
   ```
2. 設定ファイルコピー

   ```
   $ sudo cp /usr/share/doc/unionfs-fuse/examples/S01a-unionfs-fuse-live-cd.sh /etc/init.d/a-unionfs-fuse-live-cd
   $ sudo cp /usr/share/doc/unionfs-fuse/examples/rc.local.omit-pid.sh /usr/local/sbin/a-unionfs-fuse-omit-pid.sh
   ```
3. /etc/init.d/a-unionfs-fuse-live-cd を編集

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   ### BEGIN INIT INFO
   # Provides: a-unionfs-fuse-live-cd
   # Required-Start: mountall-bootclean
   # Required-Stop:
   # Default-Start: S
   # Default-Stop:
   # X-Start-Before: procps udev-mtab urandom
   # Short-Description: UnionFS mode
   # Descrition: Shutdown process will not be required
   ### END INIT INFO
   # Copyright: Bernd Schubert <bernd.schubert@fastmail.fm>
   # BSD license, see LICENSE file for details
   FUSE_OPT="-o allow_other,use_ino,suid,dev,nonempty"
   CHROOT_PATH="/tmp/unionfs"
   UNION_OPT="-ocow,chroot=$CHROOT_PATH,max_files=32768"
   UBIN=/usr/bin/unionfs-fuse
   cd /boot
   file=noprotect
   if [ -e ${file} ]; then
           echo "${file} exists"
       exit 0
   fi
   mount -o remount,ro /dev/mmcblk0p1 /boot
   mount -t proc proc /proc
   mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp
   mkdir -p $CHROOT_PATH/root
   mkdir -p $CHROOT_PATH/rw
   mkdir -p /tmp/union
   mount --bind / $CHROOT_PATH/root
   $UBIN $FUSE_OPT $UNION_OPT /rw=RW:/root=RO /tmp/union
   mount -t proc proc /tmp/union/proc
   cd /tmp/union
   mkdir oldroot
   pivot_root . oldroot
   mount -o remount,ro /dev/root /oldroot
   for d in dev run run/lock sys run/shm dev/pts boot
   do
   mount --bind /oldroot/$d /$d
   done
   init q
   /usr/local/sbin/a-unionfs-fuse-omit-pid.sh
   exit 0
   ```
4. スクリプト登録

   ```
   $ sudo update-rc.d a-unionfs-fuse-live-cd defaults
   ```
5. 切換用スクリプト作成

   - $ sudo vim /usr/local/bin/noprotect

     ```
     #!/bin/sh
     mount -o rw,remount /boot
     cd /boot
     if [ -e "protect" ]; then
         rm /boot/protect
     fi
     if [ -e "noprotect" ]; then
         echo "noprotect mode"
     else
         touch /boot/noprotect
         echo "noprotect mode"
     fi
     mount -o ro,remount /boot
     ```
   - $ sudo vim /usr/local/bin/protect

     ```
     #!/bin/sh
     mount -o rw,remount /boot
     cd /boot
     if [ -e "noprotect" ]; then
        rm /boot/noprotect
     fi
     if [ -e "protect" ]; then
        echo "protect mode"
     else
        touch /boot/protect
        echo "protect mode"
     fi
     mount -o ro,remount /boot
     ```
6. 実行権限付与

   ```
   $ sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/noprotect   
   $ sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/protect
   ```
7. 再起動
   unionfs-fuse導入前より起動に時間がかかりますが
   正常に起動します。
8. シャットダウン、または電源断を行い、その後SDカードの中を見るとすべてのファイルが消えています。

解決策をご存知の方、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 最終的にやりたいことは、`/`(root)をread-onlyでマウントして、sdcardへの書き込みを無くしたい、ということでしょうか

Answer (score 1):

私も同じ症状に遭遇しました。
結論としては、2017/3/4 現在の最新 rasbian イメージと unionfs 導入のサイトの情報には差異があり、そのままでは unionfs を導入できないのではと思います。
私も解決策を探りましたが時間切れで aufs を入れたカーネルのリビルドで ROM 化の対処を行いました。
以下詳細です。

- 対象 Raspi イメージ
  2017-01-11-raspbian-jessie.img
- 作業日
  2017/3/2 - 3/3
- 症状
  ご質問者様と同じように unionfs を他のサイトを参考に導入。最初のリブートはできるが２回目はできない。

調べた部分。

- RAMDISK 化で /tmp を tmpfs にしており、それが悪いのかと思いやめてみた。また /dev/shm など今の Rasbian イメージに沿っていない部分も見つけたので微修正。繰り返しリブートはできるが unionfs 全く機能していない様子。
- スクリプトのコマンドを root 権限で逐一実行すると pivot_root 命令でパラメータが違います、というエラーが出ている。リブートできない理由はおそらく root システムの変更がうまくいっていないためと判断した。
- そうこういている間に、Raspi 実機での aufs を入れたカーネルのビルドに成功したので調査打ち切り。

以上です。

Answer (score 1):

質問者さんの質問を見て興味を持ったので、
raspbian でなく archlinuxarm にインストールしてみました。

まず unionfs-fuse をインストールし、

```
pacman -S unionfs-fuse
```

設定ファイルを2つ作り、

/usr/lib/initcpio/install/unionfs:

```
#!/bin/bash

build() {
    add_binary "/usr/bin/unionfs"
    add_binary "/usr/bin/unionfsctl"
    add_module "fuse"

    add_runscript
}

help() {
    cat <<HELPEOF
This hook uses unionfs.
HELPEOF
}

# vim: set ft=sh ts=4 sw=4 et:
```

/usr/lib/initcpio/hooks/unionfs:

```
#!/usr/bin/ash

unionfs_mount_handler () {
    cd /tmp
    mkdir -p unionfs/root
    mount -o ro $root unionfs/root

    mkdir -p /boot
    mount --fstab unionfs/root/etc/fstab -o ro /boot
    noprotect=0
    [ -e /boot/noprotect ] && noprotect=1
    umount /boot

    umount unionfs/root
    rmdir -p unionfs/root
    cd /

    if [ $noprotect = 1 ]; then
        default_mount_handler $1
        return
    fi

    cd /tmp
    mkdir -p unionfs/root
    mkdir -p unionfs/rw
    mount -o ro $root unionfs/root
    mount -t tmpfs none unionfs/rw
    unionfs -o allow_other,use_ino,suid,dev,nonempty -ocow,chroot=/tmp/unionfs /rw=RW:/root=RO $1
}

run_hook () {
    mount_handler=unionfs_mount_handler
}
```

/etc/mkinitcpio.conf に上記を読み込む設定を行い、

```
HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block filesystems keyboard fsck unionfs"
```

initramfs image を作成しました。

```
mkinitcpio -p linux-raspberrypi
```

概ね動いているようです。何度 reboot しても問題ありません。
ただ、denbnddb さんの回答には pivot_root でエラーが出たとありますが、
archlinuxarm では代わりに switch_root というコマンドを使っており、
この違いが私の環境でうまくいっている理由なのかもしれません。

うまく動かなかった時には以下のような調査をしました。shell が動く前提ですが。

- `exit` を試してみる。init が死んで panic するかもしれないが、それはそれで経験になる。
- ls を実行しようとして ls が見つからない場合、代わりに `echo *` を試してみる。
- `mount -t proc proc /proc` してみる。
  mount 状況が見られるようになるし、ps コマンドも使えるようになる。
- もし、unionfs-fuse の PID が判って、/proc も使えるなら、
  `cd /proc/PID/cwd` により、unionfs-fuse のカレントディレクトリに移動できる。
  つまり、pivot_root してしまった後でも、unionfs-fuse が見ている filesystem を見ることができる。

以上、そもそも raspbian と archlinuxarm では随分違う気もしますので、
ある程度の参考になれば、と思い、回答として書かせていただきました。